# How to open firefox in -private-window mode using bookmark?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I tried
`file://localhost/C:/Program%20Files/Firefox%20Developer%20Edition/firefox.exe -private-window https://capweb.ru` but it wants to download firefox.exe instead of opening the link in private mode.

Comment: Haven't tried it myself, but there's *Always Open Privately* extension, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/always-open-privately/: Firefox add-on to always open specific websites in private windows.